# SQL Inner joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a little question about my SQL query. I select `descriçao`, `dtinicamp` from table `cab_doc` and `quantidade`, `id_estab` from `lin_doc` and then I inner join the info. But this does not show me the data the way I want.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT descricao, dt_ini_camp, quantidade, id_estab
  FROM cab_doc INNER JOIN lin_doc ON cab_doc.id = lin_doc.id_cab_doc
```

**Output:**

```
xxxxx 12-05-14  1000  01 
xxxxx 12-05-14  1222  03
```

What I want to achieve:

```
xxxxx 12-05-12  1000  01
                1222  03
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How soon we forget the lessons of Y2K!  Is the result you want to achieve supposed to list `12-05-14` like in the current output?  IMO, you should normally delegate such issues of presentation to the presentation layer, leaving the DBMS just to return the data.  However, I'm probably in an old-fashioned minority thinking that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT descricao, dt_ini_camp, quantidade
  FROM cab_doc INNER JOIN lin_doc ON cab_doc.id=lin_doc.id_cab_doc
 GROUP BY ROLLUP(descricao, dt_ini_camp)
```

You would have to forego the id column or bring it in some other way...

Google 'group by rollup' and correct the syntax if I am wrong.

These may be good for your reference:

- MySQL manual [GROUP BY modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)
- MySQL forum [GROUP BY .. WITH ROLLUP HAVING](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?12,106959,106959)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(descricao, dt_ini_camp)

Comment: Buddy u r using MySQL...i thought you were using Oracle. U shud mention that..lemme check what can be done with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You should really be doing this type of manipulation in the application layer, not in the database.  The reason is that the result set is not really a SQL result set because columns are missing values.  All of a sudden, the order of the result set matters, for instance.

You *can* do this.  In MySQL, the easiest way is to use variables:

```
SELECT if(@d = descricao and @dt = dt_ini_camp, '', descricao) as descricao,
       if(@d = descricao and @dt = dt_ini_camp, '', dt_ini_camp) as dt_ini_camp,
       quantidade, id_estab,
       @d := descricao,  @dt := dt_ini_camp
FROM cab_doc INNER JOIN
     lin_doc
     ON cab_doc.id = lin_doc.id_cab_doc CROSS JOIN
     (select @d := '', @dt := '') const
ORDER BY descricao, dt_ini_camp, quantidade, id_estab;
```